# How can I use jQuery to match a value to a name in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object consisting of strings for the name and arrays for the value. Given a string within one of the arrays, how can I find the name it belongs to?

Example: Given the following JSON object, how can I use jQuery to get the answer "G1" when given the string "1" or "G2" when given the string "4"?

```
{
    "G1": [ "1" , "2" ],
    "G2": [ "3" , "4" ]
}
```

I've made a JSFiddle with my current work: http://jsfiddle.net/JmX6b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result;
for (var key in json) {
  if (json[key].indexOf(input) != -1) {
    result = key;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: requires a shim for `Array.indexOf` in IE versions lower than 8. [here's one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm). Since the question is tagged jQuery, [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) could be used instead, if a shim is not desired.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yep, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/alokswain/9wVQh/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all keys in your object with `for ... in`. From there, you can iterate over each item. If you find the appropriate entry, simply yield the key you were currently at.

```
$("button").click(function() {

    var input = $("input").val();

    for(key in json) {
       for(var i = 0, l < json[key].length; i < l; i++) {
          if(json[key][i] == input) {
             $('code').html(key);
             return;
          }
       }
    }

    $('code').html('Item not found');

);
```